# Label of multiline text input broken?

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a `TextInput` that I've set to multiline. It has a long title and this is rendered as a broken label (wrong position).

Am I setting things incorrectly ?

```
function onDefaultHomePageOpen(e) {
  let introText = CardService.newTextParagraph()
    .setText(UNREGISTERED_INTRO_TEXT);

  let checkAddressAction = CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName("checkInputAddress")
    .setLoadIndicator(CardService.LoadIndicator.SPINNER);

  let addrInput = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName(USER_REF_ADDRESS)
    .setTitle("Quelle est votre adresse de départ habituelle ? (votre domicile ou votre bureau)")
    .setMultiline(true)
    .setOnChangeAction(checkAddressAction);

  /* some other stuff here */

  let homeSection = CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(introText)
    .addWidget(addrInput)
    .addWidget(transportModeInput)
    .addWidget(validateButton);
 
  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .addSection(homeSection)
    .build()
}
```

When value is empty
[image: broken label]

When I have typed something
[image: label is ok when I type]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the style guide it looks to be a bad idea to use long texts specially for text input labels as the style guide suggests to use short text.

You might use a shorter text as the textinput label and put a brief explanation as a hint.

From the [Copy Macros](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/share-macro), a Workspace add-ons sample:

```
.addWidget(CardService.newTextInput()
   .setFieldName('sourceScriptId')
   .setValue(sourceScriptId || '')
   .setTitle('Script ID of the source macro')
   .setHint('You must have at least edit permission for the source spreadsheet to access its script project'))
```

---

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/guides/workspace-style#text_inputs

> #### Writing style
>
> You shouldn’t need to write much. Most actions should
> be made clear through iconography, layout, and short labels. If you
> find a portion of your add-on needs more extensive explanation than
> short labels can provide, it's a best practice to create a separate
> web page describing your add-on and link to it.
>
> When writing UI text:
>
> - Use sentence case (especially for buttons, labels, and card actions).
> - Prefer short, simple text without jargon or acronyms.

Comment: yes I suppose that's the only acceptable answer... :-D